# Effective number of samples (ENS) and evaluation metric choice

Tags: loss-functions, model-evaluation, unbalanced-classes, tuning

I have a question regarding the appropriate evaluation metric for my problem. I'm working on a classification problem with highly imbalanced classes. I've decided to employ [ENS](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPR_2019/papers/Cui_Class-Balanced_Loss_Based_on_Effective_Number_of_Samples_CVPR_2019_paper.pdf) (effective number of samples) loss to combat this issue of imbalanced classes.
I tune my models so that I try to minimize this "modified" loss.

My question is, what metric would be appropriate to use for a fair evaluation?
I found out that macro-F1 is usually a good choice for imbalanced classes, but I worry that, in my case, this would be redundant or even wrong.
Should I instead use micro-F1? Or should I ditch the ENS, and calculate the "normal" loss while tuning my models with macro-F1 maximization (and also evaluating them on macro-F1)?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148006/discussion-on-question-by-arya513-effective-number-of-samples-ens-and-evaluati); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.